# PHP while loop problems

Tags: php, loops

I am primarily a CSS and HTML guy but I have recently ventured into PHP.

I can't see why this script hangs:

```
$loop_Until = 10;

while($i < $loop_Until)
{
    // do some code here
    $loop_Until = $loop_Until + 1;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is the range you are expecting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is causing an ifinate loop, youo will want to take a look at the php `for` loop. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

```
for($i= 1; $i< $loop_Until; ++$i) {
    // do some code here
}
```

You are increasing `$loop_Until` every time and never increaing `$i` therefore `$i` will always be less than `$loop_Until`

Answer (score 18):

**Fixed Code**

```
$loop_Until = 10;
$i = 0;

    while($i < $loop_Until)
    {
        // do some code here
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
```

**Explanation of your code:**

```
// A variable called loop until is set to 10
$loop_Until = 10;  

// While the variable i is less than 10
// NOTE:  i is not set in code snippet, so we have no way of knowing what value it is, if it is greater than 10 it might be infinite
while($i < $loop_Until)
{
    // Increment the 10 value up 1 every time, i never changes!
    $loop_Until = $loop_Until + 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the original while construct, instead of rewriting as a for.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of his initial code - it's always good to actually know WHY something isn't working as expected.

Comment: @danp: That's a plus... how?  idio said they had previously only used HTML and CSS and may not have known about `for` loops, which are the correct construct to use for looping with a counter.

Comment: No assumptions, the OP asks about a while, best to reply with that in mind. Nothing wrong with saying "by the way.... a for does this", but keep things in context :)

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest solution: Replace your "+" with a "-"**. This will cause the loop to end. Like this:

```
$loop_Until = 10;

while($i < $loop_Until)
{
    // do some code here
    $loop_Until = $loop_Until - 1;
}
```

Let me explain, provide a slightly better solution, and give you a few alternatives.

If we assume that $i starts out as smaller than $loop_Until, then adding 1 to $loop_Until with the line `$loop_Until = $loop_Until + 1;` would never make it so that $i is equal or greater than $loop_Until.

You should either subtract from $loop_Until, or add to $i.

Subtracting 1 from a variable can be done quickly by doing, `--$variable`.
Adding 1 to a variable can be done quickly by doing, `++$variable`, so you should have:

```
$loop_Until = 10;

while($i < $loop_Until)
{
    // do some code here
    --$loop_Until;
}
```

**Of course $loop_Until sounds like something you might want to set once, and then have it stay unchanged.** In this case, you can set $i and increment that. So first set $i to whatever you want (smaller than $loop_Until, if you want your while loop to run at least once), then:

```
$loop_Until = 10;

while($i < $loop_Until)
{
    // do some code here
    ++$i;
}
```

Incidentally, [++$i is faster than $i++](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

As Lizard mentioned, the for loop is great for doing this. The two equivalent for loops for the two sections of code above are

```
for($loop_Until = 10; $i < $loop_Until; --$loop_Until)
{
    // do some code here
}
```

and

```
for($loop_Until = 10; $i < $loop_Until; ++i)
{
    // do some code here
}
```

Just make sure you check that your condition will eventually happen with a few numbers on a piece of paper or in your head.

Finally, which of these solutions you pick will depend on whether you want $i or $loop_Until to remain unchanged.

If you have multiple loops, and you want to do all of them the same amount of times, it's probably a good idea to leve $loop_Until untouched, and reset $i at the beginning of each loop.

Comment: `++$i vs $i++` is a great example of micro-optimization. Whoa, it seems you save whole 0.6 μs everytime you use `++$i` instead of `$i++`!

Comment: Yeah. It's a nice habit to get into. Readability is equivalent, keystrokes are equivalent, but you do make a mini difference, so you might as well... also it teaches you about the difference between the two, since they're not always interchangeable (see TheBoss' answer)

Answer (score 0):

`while( 0 != ($loop_until--) );`

Comment: Why are you assuming 0 is a number of significance. OP wants to compare to $i.... also, why not while($loop_until--) if you want to compare to 0.